# Change background of iframe

Tags: css, iframe

Website goo.gl/4nQia8

How do i remove the black background in the widget called whos online.
I have spent sometime searching for that css but i cant find it or manipulate it.

I have changed everything that is called background in my css without anyhelp.
Also tryied  to add style to the iframe didnt help.

```css
allowtransparency="true" style="background: none;"
```

I want 100% transperent i have tested everything that i can.

Comment: there's custom css on the body. background color is #161522. You need to change (or move) this css as it affects the whole body. As it's custom css on a wp site, it seems this may not be a default colour, that you may have added it? If this is not the unwanted colour, please clarify your question.

Comment: Did you managed to find the css or did you do a color analizer in photoshop?

Comment: I inspected the code using firebug

Comment: Ok but the question is clear how do i remove #161522 color from that area?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is affecting your iframe:

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #161522; }
</style>
```

To remove the colour from the area you want, you could create a 'wrapper' div for the first two columns, and apply the `custom-background-css` only to the wrapper div as opposed to the `body`  and then the entire body would not be affected, only the sections you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: body.custom-background { background-color: none; } did only change the footer background.

I managed to change background now but i cant use code none or transparent.

Comment: @FastXX i didn't suggest you use either none or transparent. By the way, there is also another background color, #202020, specified in the css. I would suggest looking at the css first before posting questions. If you want a plain background you could use white. But you would need to separate the avatar div

Comment: Ok thanks man <3 But still its a wierd problem for me i have never got this problem so i dont know how to solve it. So ok you are saying something about #202020. The avatar is separated i think. The complete code is <frame 100wX30h f> its in this iframe that background color apears. But i dont know where the .css is for that cause i cant inspect it.

Comment: #202020 is the background colour in the body in the wp stylesheet css. The code for your iframe that you posted can be easily inspected live by right-clicking on your site and clicking 'inspect'. Or you can view the source code! your 'Who's Online' is within an aside. Change the css of the aside.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it!

In the actual .php thats why i could not find it.

```css
<table style="width:361px;background:none;"
<tr style="width:361px;background:none;"
```